# JSON Schema: array with exactly n elements of given sub-schemas

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to figure out how can I write a JSON Schema for an array which has to contain exactly 2 elements, where each of those elements conform to its own subschema. I've got no idea at all, since none of `anyOf`, `allOf`, `oneOf` don't suit well here.

Let's say that I've got `ss1` and `ss2` subschemas that define elements of type `t1` and `t2`, respectively. How can I write a schema which will accept arrays that one element of type `t1` (conforming to `ss1`) and another element of type `t2` (conforming to `ss2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `items` keyword has a special format just for this.  Instead of the value being a schema, it can be an array of schemas.  When `items` is used this way, the items in the array must conform to the corresponding schema in the `items` array of schemas.  Here is a working example assuming t1 = string and t2 = integer.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/ss1" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/ss2" }
  ],
  "minItems": 2,
  "maxItems": 2,
  "definitions": {
    "ss1": { "type": "string" },
    "ss2": { "type": "integer" }
  }
}
```